# Cannot search user by name on stackexchange.com

Tags: support, search

This is regarding search facility on stackoverflow.com. The advanced search tips mention that we can search for users using "user:name" in search box. But it is not working for my name (rnso). I have to search for my posts through google. Where could be the problem? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try `user:me` instead?

Comment: OK. It does work this way but that means I cannot search for my posts if I am not logged in.

Comment: Where do you see anything saying you can use "user:name" in the help?

Comment: You can use the [users tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `Id` of the user instead of the name cause there can be multiple users with the same name.

If you want to search for your post you can use [user:me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me). If you want to find my post as an example you need to use [user:83039](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:83039)

Comment: It is surprising that multiple users can have same username on this site.